# Can't set remote Git at shared hosting via https protocol

Tags: git

I need to set remote Git origin located at my shared hosting via https protocol instead of ssh. From the root of my hosting account, the path to the `/repo` dir is like `/home/user123/public_html/repo`. In my local machine I add the remote origin by the command

```
git remote add origin https://user123:password@example.com/home/user123/public_html/repo
```

and next run the command

```
git push -u origin master
```

but I get the error

> fatal: repository
> 'https://example.com/home/user123/public_html/repo/' not found

Comment: Are you sure about the `home/user123` part? Generally web servers start in `/var/www/` or similar, and `public_html` directories in user directories are signified by `https://example.com/~user/repo/` for instance.

Comment: Yes, the path `home/user123/public_html/repo` is correct. My hosting provider uses Linux and cPanel

Comment: I don't know which exactly password I should specify in the url, so I specified the password to cPanel account. Maybe it's the reason of the problem?

Comment: The password is up to the web server too, so see whatever your particular web server requires. The usual (which apparently isn't the case for *this* server) is that you need whatever password goes with whatever `user@host` account you're using, in this case `user123`.

Comment: I've just did the steps which are described at the https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#public-repositories and now try the url like `https://example.com/~user/proj.git` but I still get the error `repository https://example.com/~user/proj.git/ not found`

Comment: If I were doing this myself, I'd log in to the server (`example.com`) and go poke through the http server logs to see what's going on, at this point. There are a lot of different servers these days, each with its own quirks and features: the stuff above was pioneered, more or less, in the old Apache httpd, but that was in the 1990s...